# Parsing XML with a File in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, xml

My issue is to display file coming from a XML Response on the iPhone using UIDocumentInteraction Controller. I am unable to convert this file.The guy who is doing web-service is saying that its a binary data.
Please refer to the following XML Response

> < NewDataSet>
>  < Table diffgr:id="Table1"
>   msdata:rowOrder="0">
>  <  FILE > 
>   UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDd/JU3ZgEAACAFAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   < /FILE >
>  < FILENAME >New Word Doucment < / FILENAME >
>  <
>   FILETYPE >doc< /FILETYPE > 
> < RESULT>SUCCESS< /RESULT >
>  <
>   /Table >
>  < /NewDataSet >

I have trimmed the FILE tag.. it will be really very huge

I have parsed the xml and stored the content of < FILE > tag into "**filePath**"  I am doing the following

```
const char *utfString = [filePath UTF8String];
//filepath contains the string for FILE
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes: utfString length: strlen(utfString)];

//NSData *myData = [Base64 decode:filePath];
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
//       
NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", fileName,fileType];
NSString *newPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
[myData writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES];
myData=nil;
```

Please let me know how to parse this XML and save the file or just display it.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472634/iphone-soap-connection-ideas/6473624#6473624).

Comment: I have found the solution for this Problem... We may have to do base 64 decoding for that and I have am using the base 64 decoding options provided [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filestring should be decoded using base64 decoding. I have used the code provided in the following url [Base 64 Decoding](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour)